# Most common everyday phrases in Japanese

Tags: phrases

Does anyone have a list, or know of a list of the most commonly used phrases in japanese? The bigger the list the better.

Comment: `sou desu ne/ka` <-- your list. In all seriousness though, we try to avoid questions that can't actually have an answer. Good sources for this sort of material would be any basic japanese textbook.

Comment: @jkerian the problem is I'm looking for a list up to the thousands scale. I'm using this for my program and I would rather not type out thousands of lines from textbooks.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I suspect most of the people who voted to close this question did so under the impression that you were a new student looking for an 'efficient' study method. Searching for a technical speech corpus can certainly be considered within the bounds of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Any JLPT syllabus (such as [this one](http://www.jlptstudy.com/)) is likely to contain many common phrases (such as [these](http://www.jlptstudy.com/N5/N5_expression-list.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The corpora listed at http://research.nii.ac.jp/src/eng/list/index.html are focused on speech, but that is probably the direction you'd like to go. (written collections will be heavily biased towards 'netspeak' or 'newspaper language')