# Looking for Japanese common speech phrases list

Tags: resources, phrases

I'm looking for a large comprehensive list of phrases that are commonly used by the Japanese, anyone know of some resources for that?

I've seen the list on [here](http://research.nii.ac.jp/src/eng/list/index.html) but most of them aren't exactly what I need, are there any other sources?

Comment: How are the nii.ac sources not exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: @jkerian
most of those are simply experiments testing different aspects of speech, the people in the experiments are made to read long passages or specific words. In one case there are passages about how to talk with a car dealer. Sure there are a few here and there that are useful, but from the summary it seems they are very few in numbers. I'm looking for a large list, not experiments on speech in loud environments or how different dialects sound.

Comment: note that I have no use for large passages of conversation or story, the JLPT study guide has the kind of list I'm looking for but unfortunately few in numbers

Comment: Some corpus seem to have structured (parsed) data. If you analyze that and extract the frequent phrases, would that do?

Comment: If you are after a *list* of phrases, then corpora are specifically *not* what you are after. A corpus is by definition a collection of actually occurring language, used by linguists to find patterns, test hypotheses, etc. (E.g. you might think that verb X is mostly used in form Y, but then you check the corpus and find that Y is actually relatively uncommon and Z is preferred.) Corpora are full of repetition, dialect, mistakes, etc. Enno Shioji's suggestion might help you extract a cleanly formatted list of phrases from one, but it seems more trouble than it'd be worth.

Comment: @Matt looks like i got misdirected in thinking corpora was what I needed. I've changed the title to fit my actual needs

Comment: @Matt: Then again though, if he really means "common" in the strict sense (as in statistically frequently used), it could be the way to go. Or would a manually compiled list do (i.e. "common" as in perceived to be common by the authors)? I think that's an important point to clarify.

Comment: @Enno Shioji That's a good point, maybe I was too absolutist. I guess common phrases would be in a corpus (at least common to whatever context that corpus was focused on), and you could even use the corpus to see just how common each phrase was. It's just that they'd be embedded in so much crap, with no obvious differentiation from the crap, that I can't imagine corpus-trawling to be the best way to get such a list.

Comment: Do you mean specifically set-phrases?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes like http://www.jlptstudy.com/N2/index.html

Comment: When I first started learning Japenese I found a phrase book like that and studied it and ... after 8 years of living in Japan I assure you that any phrase book you buy will be C@#$%p. The problem is if you learn phrases for the western side of Japan they will sound funny in the eastern side and if the phrase book was written by a women then you will sound like a girl and if it was written by an old guy then you will sound like an old man and then there are all the different situations where you can or can't use specific phrases that we would have no problem using in English.

Comment: Now what would be great would be a book that separates all the phrases by the age and sex and location of the speaker and each situation they are in. Only then would a phrase book be useful and not harmful.

Comment: @mugetsu, Hey I have an idea. I will try to work on this if you come up with a handful of English phrases. I will try to put those in Japanese and separate them into all these contexts... what say you?

Comment: This is off-topic for the main site but would be okay on meta. From the amount of conversation it has generated it may be better still on chat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [most common everyday phrases in japanese](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3208/most-common-everyday-phrases-in-japanese)